# Are there any benefits to moving async scripts to the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with a `script` tag in HEAD section:

```
<script src="somescript.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

As it contains `async` attribute it loads asynchronously and browser parses the page without waiting for this script to be downloaded. Once downloaded, this script will execute, also asynchronously so browser can continue on parsing the page.

This script, once downloaded will perform some actions and inserts yet another script dynamically via something similar to this:

```
var a = document.createElement('script');
    a.type = 'text/javascript';
    a.src = 'http://domain/otherscript.js';

    var elem_body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; 
    elem_body.appendChild(a);
```

This new dynamically inserted script will also be executed asynchronously and again browser can continue on to other things, so parsing the page or executing other scripts as needed.

Now, my understanding is that this script, from beginning to the end of its execution will not block browser in any way. It will load, insert another script and execute completely asynchronously. `DOMContentLoaded event will not be slow down at all.

It will however slow down window's `onload` event as until this script is executed completely this event will not fire.

My question is would there be any benefit to moving this to the bottom of the page? It seems that as everything happens asynchronously it would not make any difference apart from the `<script ..>` tag call itself. If anything it could actually slow down `onload` event as this will be executed only when everything is done including asynchronous scripts execution. As this script would start when the page is almost parsed `onload` event would be possibly delayed further waiting for this last script to do its thing.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It depends on what browser compatibility you are expecting. Here is a useful link: http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async. I personally prefer putting g scripts tags just before the closing body tag. I think it is considered best practice and is part of the top 10 page performance improvements recommended by Yahoo. That was a little while ago thou, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if the browser does not support `async`. If it does not, it will block execution wherever it finds the `<script>` tag. I would put it at the bottom just in case.

Comment: Wouldn't that possibly delay on load event though? Or I'm misunderstanding something here

Comment: I believe so, the best practice is to place all render blocking scripts at the bottom of your HTML. The browser has to finish loading the page before it fires the load event. This is all assuming `aync` is not supported of course.

Comment: thanks, in regards to onload event delay I asked another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587190/will-script-loaded-with-async-attribute-delay-onload-event, I hope it will not be marked as duplicate