# Will script loaded with async attribute delay onload event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a page with a `script` tag in HEAD section:

```
<script src="somescript.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

As it contains `async` attribute it loads asynchronously and browser parses the page without waiting for this script to be downloaded. Once downloaded, this script will execute, also asynchronously so browser can continue on parsing the page.

This script, once downloaded will perform some actions and inserts yet another script dynamically via something similar to this:

```
var a = document.createElement('script');
    a.type = 'text/javascript';
    a.src = 'http://domain/otherscript.js';

    var elem_body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; 
    elem_body.appendChild(a);
```

This new dynamically inserted script will also be executed asynchronously and again browser can continue on to other things, so parsing the page or executing other scripts as needed.

Now, my understanding is that this script, from beginning to the end of its execution will not block browser in any way. It will load, insert another script and execute completely asynchronously. `DOMContentLoaded` event will not be slow down at all.

Hoever, will this possibly delay firing of `onload` event? It seems to me that as this script would start when the page is almost parsed. Then it would request other scripts and `onload` event would be possibly delayed further waiting for this last script to do its thing.

Is my understanding correct?

**EDIT**

Added test at http://plnkr.co/edit/BCDPdgCjPeNUmLbf7wNR?p=preview 
and in Chrome it seems that it does delay onload event

Comment: as described, onload() would most likely fire before otherscript.js executed, but a simple test would suffice.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as you suggest, it will delay the `window.onload` event.

Your first script, `somescript.js` adds a child `script` element to the page, before the page has finished loading (e.g. before `window.onload` has fired), and the page now has to download and execute the src of that newly appended `script` element before it can fire an `onload` event.

If you didn't want it to delay the `onload` event, you could make an `AJAX` request to get the contents of `otherscript.js` and simply `eval` it so it executes in the global context (effectively the same as specifying it via a `script` tag, but without delaying the `onload` event).